# Is here any GUI tool that can show file with conflicts side-by-side?

Tags: git, meld, kdiff3

I have a couple of conflicted files and I don't have access to source branches (these files are detached from the repository. There isn't any *.git* folder and I don't have original versions). There are some conflicts marked by `git-merge`:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    sizeof(.......bla bla
||||||| merged common ancestors
    sizeof(.......ble ble
=======
    sizeof(.......blu blu
>>>>>>> refs/heads/TAGNAME
```

Is there a way to see such file in human-readable mode, i.e. parse a single file with marked conflicts and split it to a side-by-side view?  I suppose [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) cannot do it, and [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) seems to be unable to do the trick too.

git merge (tool) says that this isn't a Git repository.

`git diff --no-index` requires two parameters (two files to compare), and as mentioned before I don't have the input files.

Comment: Any major IDE can do this, e.g. IntelliJ or Eclipse if you are working with Java.

Comment: How about sourceTree?

Comment: I'm curious, why did you put the [tag:kdiff3] tag on your question, when that's a tool designed to do exactly what you're asking?

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please check what topics you can ask here ([help/on-topic]).

Comment: David Z: So tell me please how to achieve it with kdiff3. The only effects I observe is one panel fillend and empty second panel or the information that files are identical when I'm trying to open the same file twice - on both panels.

Answer (score 0):

Use [P4Merge](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge) to visualize the differences. You can [set it up as the default tool](https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372) used by Git-Diff and Git-Merge. Here is [the effect](https://www.perforce.com/sites/default/files/p4merge_three_pane_1.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Meld can indeed handle visualising conflicts

Source: *[Resolving merge conflicts](http://meldmerge.org/help/resolving-conflicts.html)*

[image]